# How to get province and city from google map - ios

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

this is my url to get province and city name from google map:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=35.6961880572782,51.3820192962885&key=AIzaSyAdEzHZfZWyjLMuuW92w5fkR86S3-opIF0&language=fa&region=IR&locale=fa

but there is a problem. sometimes it returns different JSON structure and I don't know how can I get the province and city.

Answer (score 0):

There are three keys available for province and city. These key are administrative area_1, administrative area_2 and administrative area_3 .
You need to check for these key. Sometimes only few keys available in the json. First priority is area1 then area2 and area3 respectively.